# Openshift v3 webhook for github.com

Tags: github, openshift, webhooks

I tried to add webhook for github. I copied webhook from build's page and add it to github repo. And obtained 401 Unautorized.

Same result:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT" -X POST -k https://api.preview.openshift.com/oapi/v1/namespaces/project.metadata.name/buildconfigs/buildConfig.metadata.name/webhooks/mysecret/github

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 16 Oct 2016 16:12:42 GMT
Content-Length: 228

{
"kind": "Status",
"apiVersion": "v1",
"metadata": {},
"status": "Failure",
"message": "the webhook \"github\" for \"buildConfig.metadata.name\" did not accept your secret",
"reason": "Unauthorized",
"code": 401
}
```

Issue list of OpenShift Origin contains something like this, but it was fixed.

```
$oc version

oc v1.3.0
kubernetes v1.3.0+52492b4
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://api.preview.openshift.com:443
openshift v3.3.0.35
kubernetes v1.3.0+52492b4
```

Comment: What template or image stream were you using?

Comment: It does'nt matter. QuickStarts rails, cakephp. Very simpe example like: index.php with <?php phphinfo(); ?> works well, but webhook still 401 HTTP Anwer.